# codeigniter database fetching problems

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
public function fetch_user_added_ads_display() {
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('user_added_ads');
    $this->db->join('media_ads','media_ads.user_added_ads_id=user_added_ads.user_added_ads_id');
    $this->db->group_by('user_added_ads.user_added_ads_id');
    $this->db->limit('3');
    $q=$this->db->get();

    return $q->result();
}
```

Hello friends can anyone please suggest me how can i fetch data from database, that is i need from 4th row to 8th row,so how can i do it in codeigniter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to fetch data from row 4th to 8th then please edit limit line as follow :

```
    $this->db->limit(3,4);
```

Here 3 is offset which is the 4th one as it starts from 0. 4 specify no of records to be fetched.

Answer (score 1):

as per my opinion

```
 $this->db->limit('3');
```

change this code use below code

```
$this->db->limit(5,3);
```

it will work